# What does "there is no smaller array object that satisfies these constraints" mean?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

The draft n4659 for C++17 describes the general principes of the language in chapter 4. In chapter 4.5, The C++ object model [intro.object], I cannot understand the meaning of one sentence (emphasize mine)

> 3 If a complete object is created (8.3.4) in storage associated with another object e of type “array of N
>   unsigned char” or of type “array of N std::byte” (21.2.1), that array provides storage for the created
>   object if:
>   (3.1) — the lifetime of e has begun and not ended, and
>   (3.2) — the storage for the new object fits entirely within e, and
>   (3.3) — **there is no smaller array object that satisfies these constraints.**

while examples show that an array can provide storage for elements much shorter than the array:

```
struct A { unsigned char a[32]; };
struct B { unsigned char b[16]; };
A a;
B *b = new (a.a + 8) B; // a.a provides storage for *b
int *p = new (b->b + 4) int; // b->b provides storage for *p
```

here `*p` uses only 4 bytes (assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4) in a 16 bytes array. So, what is the meaning of 3.3?

Comment: My uninformed guess. You could place a char array within a larger char array, and another object within the smaller char array. The smaller array wiill then provide storage for the other object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning if 3.3 is to differentiate `a[32]` from `b[16]`. The former doesn't provide storage for `*p` because the latter does. It identifies the smallest unique array object that provides the region of storage where the object resides.

Without 3.3 the definition would be transitive. `a[32]` would provide storage for `*p` because it ultimately provides storage for `b[16]`.

---

Regarding `*p` using 4 bytes. It's important to note that the region `[b->b + 4, b->b +8)`, while being the storage where `*p` resides, is not the array object providing the storage (that region isn't an array object at all). That smallest array object would be `b->b`.