# How is [intro.object]/3 in the C++17 Standard Reference to be understood?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[intro.object]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#3) of N4659 (March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS) states that:

> If a complete object is created ([expr.new]) in storage associated
>   with another object *e* of type “array of *N* `unsigned char`” or of type
>   “array of *N* `std​::​byte`” ([cstddef.syn]), that array provides storage
>   for the created object if:
>
> (3.1) the lifetime of *e* has begun and not ended, and
>
> (3.2) the storage for the new object fits entirely within *e*, and
>
> (3.3) there is no smaller array object that satisfies these
>   constraints.
>
> [ Note: If that portion of the array previously provided storage for
>   another object, the lifetime of that object ends because its storage
>   was reused ([basic.life]).  — end note ]
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> template<typename ...T>
> struct AlignedUnion {
>   alignas(T...) unsigned char data[max(sizeof(T)...)];
> };
> int f() {
>   AlignedUnion<int, char> au;
>   int *p = new (au.data) int;     // OK, au.data provides storage
>   char *c = new (au.data) char(); // OK, ends lifetime of *p
>   char *d = new (au.data + 1) char();
>   return *c + *d; // OK
> }
> struct A { unsigned char a[32]; };
> struct B { unsigned char b[16]; };
> A a;
> B *b = new (a.a + 8) B;      // a.a provides storage for *b
> int *p = new (b->b + 4) int; // b->b provides storage for *p
>                              // a.a does not provide storage for *p (directly),
>                              // but *p is nested within a (see below)
> ```
>
> — end example]

- How is this text supposed to be understood?

  - How does that work out and harmonize with the basic things about arrays e.g. sizeof(array)?
  - Besides pointers, what other complete objects do arrays provide storage for?

I will appreciate illustrations that would demonstrate the what's said here so that I can fully understand this text.

Comment: would be easier to answer if you refer to the example and explain what parts of it are unclear

Comment: you need to tell us what is unclear to you.

Comment: what does `sizeof(array)` have to do with anything? Where did you get that arrays provide storage to pointers? I am very confused about your confusion.

Comment: If you are new to C++ and are trying to learn C++ by reading the standard then **don't**! The standard is not intended for teaching and is a very very bad tool for that. You should start reading the standard only after you have a firm grasp on C++.

Comment: @idclev463035818 okay, for example this line: int *p = new (au.data) int;     // OK, au.data provides storage. How does au.data provide storage for p?

Comment: btw the example that follows that paragraph is not storing pointers in the arrays storage, maybe thats your misunderstanding

Comment: do you know placement new ? That would be a prerequisite to understand what that paragraph is talking about. (btw it is rather advanced stuff, I never had to use something like this and I probably wont need it for long time)

Comment: for your comment: `au.data` provides storage in the sense that no memory has to be allocated because the `int` is created in the memory of `au.data`

Comment: how do you come to the conclusion that arrays would only provide storage for pointers? Your second points is based on a misunderstanding, but it isnt clear what that misunderstanding is

Comment: I actually already know that arrays hold elements of different types. But I though that the statement the "complete object created in association with the" array also meant any object created in association of with the array, including like pointers to the elements of the array etc.. @idclev463035818; so it means that the complete object referred to here is simply an element of the array right?

Comment: the "complete object" is the one that is created via `new` in the arrays storage, its an `int`, 2 `char`s then a `B` and an `int` in the example (no pointers btw)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215425/discussion-between-octopus-and-idclev-463035818).

Comment: no, please no chat. I tried to write an answer. For clarification you could answer the questions: Do you know placement new? Why do you think only pointers could be placed in an arrays storage? You can edit your question to clarify that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does that work out and harmonize with the basic things about arrays e.g. sizeof(array)?

There is no interference between what that paragraph says and `sizeof` and other properties of an array.

> Besides pointers, what other complete objects do arrays provide storage for?

It appears you misunderstood the examples. In the examples several objects are created in arrays storage via placement new. As usual `new` returns a pointer to the object, but what is stored in the arrays is the actual objects.

Difficult to explain better because your points are both based on a misunderstanding. Anyhow, take the last part of the example with slight modifications:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { unsigned char a[32]; };
struct B { 
    unsigned char b[16];
    void hello_world() {
        std::cout << "hello world";
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B *b = new (a.a + 8) B;      // a.a provides storage for *b

    std::cout << sizeof(a.a) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(b->b) << "\n";

    B& bref = *b;
    bref.hello_world();
}
```

Here a `B` is created in the storage of an `A` (more specifically in the `a` member of an `A`). Placing an object in the arrays storage has no influence on the arrays size. What is placed in the arrays storage is an object. `new` (and placement `new`) return a pointer to that object, that can be dereferenced to get a reference to the actual object.

Comment: Great thanks! but how is this part to be understood?: (3.3) there is no smaller array object that satisfies these constraints.

Comment: @octopus I was hoping you wouldnt ask, because I have absolutely no clue what that measn :P

Comment: @octopus [What does “there is no smaller array object that satisfies these constraints” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075112/what-does-there-is-no-smaller-array-object-that-satisfies-these-constraints-me)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks that was very useful.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks that was very useful.